# How to manipulate output in perl

Tags: perl

I'm new to perl and I can't find whether I can manipulate the output format in perl or not.

for a code like

```
print "$arOne[i] => $arTwo[i]\n";
```

I want the oputput to be like

```
 8 => 9
10 => 25
 7 => 456
```

If it is possible, then how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html).

```
printf ("%2d => %-3d\n", $arOne[$i], $arTwo[$i]);
```

The *formatting instructions* are embedded between the `%` and a letter. In your case, you print numbers, so you need the letter `d`. The number left to the `d` specifies how many digits you want to reserve for the number. In your case, I made the assumption that the left number consists of at most two digits, while the right number consists of at most three digits. That might vary. Finally, the `-` in front of the `3d` tells `printf` to left (rather than right) align the number.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of TMTOWTDI-ness, there's also the old facility of [perl formats](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw(each_array);

my @arOne = (8, 10, 7);
my @arTwo = (9, 25, 456);  # @arTwoDeeTwo ?  @ceeThreePO ?
my ($one, $two);

format STDOUT =
@> => @<<
$one,$two
.

# Now write to the format we described above    
my $next_pair = each_array(@arOne, @arTwo);
while (($one, $two) = $next_pair->()) {
  write;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Note that this "report generation" capability is little-used in contemporary perl programming.  The [`printf` suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16399795/132382) is typically more flexible (and less surprising).  It seemed a pity, however, not to mention formats in perl in question about formatting in perl.

Comment: It's possible to go too far with TMTOWTDI. Formats should not be used for anything.

Comment: @friedo, I don't disagree.